Align line with caption in Tikz pgfplot legend
See how the red line is below the center of the caption?
Is there a way to centrally vertically align the line of each item with the caption inside the legend?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \scalebox{1} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend style={nodes={scale=0.75,text depth=0.5em},xshift=2.5cm,yshift=.75cm,cells={anchor=center,inner ysep=4pt},row sep=4px},
            legend cell align={left},
            grid=none,axis lines = middle,
            samples=2000,smooth,width=10cm,
            xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=13,ymax=600,
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, clip mode=individual,
            extra y ticks={0,500},
            xlabel={$t$ [s]},
            ylabel={$r$ [m]},
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, clip mode=individual,
            x label style={anchor=west}, y label style={anchor=south},
        ];
        \addplot[domain=0:10,green,very thick] { 500 + 0 + 0.5*(-10)*\x*\x };
        \addlegendentry{$\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}(t_0) + \vec{v}(t_0) + \dfrac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$};
        \addplot[no marks,red,very thick] coordinates {
                (0,500) (1,500) (2,490) (3,470) (4,440) (5,400) (6,350) (7,290) (8,220) (9,140) (10,50)
            };
        \addlegendentry{$\vec{r}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{r}(t) + \vec{v}(t) \Delta t$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}



As can be seen from this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={row sep=10pt, nodes={draw, inner sep=0pt}},
legend cell align={left},
axis lines=middle,
width=10cm,
xmin=0, xmax=13,
ymin=0, ymax=600,
];
\addplot[green, very thick, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth] { 500 + 0 + 0.5*(-10)*\x*\x };
\addlegendentry{test$\dfrac{1}{2}$}
\addplot[red, very thick, smooth] coordinates {(0,500) (1,500) (2,490) (3,470) (4,440) (5,400) (6,350) (7,290) (8,220) (9,140) (10,50)};
\addlegendentry{test}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


For some reason the denominator of \dfrac is not included in the node.
Manual adjustments can be made like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={row sep=8pt},
legend cell align={left},
axis lines=middle,
width=10cm,
xmin=0, xmax=13,
ymin=0, ymax=600,
];
\addplot[green, very thick, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth] { 500 + 0 + 0.5*(-10)*\x*\x };
\addlegendentry[yshift=3pt]{$\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}(t_0) + \vec{v}(t_0) + \dfrac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$}
\addplot[red, very thick, smooth] coordinates {(0,500) (1,500) (2,490) (3,470) (4,440) (5,400) (6,350) (7,290) (8,220) (9,140) (10,50)};
\addlegendentry{$\vec{r}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{r}(t) + \vec{v}(t) \Delta t$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit:
The problem comes from the default text depth=0.15em is too small to fit the fraction - see page 260 in the manual. A way to make the legends centered without manual height adjustments is to increase text depth and text height until the content fits. e.g.
legend style={nodes={text depth=10pt, text height=15pt}},

See also answer by @egreg here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728908/8650
Edit:
The best solution thanks to @egreg:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={row sep=6pt, nodes={text depth=}},
legend cell align={left},
axis lines=middle,
width=10cm,
xmin=0, xmax=13,
ymin=0, ymax=600,
];
\addplot[green, very thick, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth] { 500 + 0 + 0.5*(-10)*\x*\x };
\addlegendentry{$\vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}(t_0) + \vec{v}(t_0) + \dfrac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$}
\addplot[red, very thick, smooth] coordinates {(0,500) (1,500) (2,490) (3,470) (4,440) (5,400) (6,350) (7,290) (8,220) (9,140) (10,50)};
\addlegendentry{$\vec{r}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{r}(t) + \vec{v}(t) \Delta t$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

